# A program that will loop under the conditions of an operator

Tags: java, loops, operators

I'm writing a java program that will count up to a number that the user inputs. The user is only allowed to input a number that is between 1-10.

For instance:

if the user entered `6` the output will be:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

How do I do this with only using operators and `while` and `if` statements?

Here's my code. I've been painfully trying to figure out why my code won't work. Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class loop_lab {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hi user, input any number that is between 1-10");{
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int num1 = input.nextInt();
            int num2 = 0;

            if (1<=num1 && num1>=10);
            num2=0;

            while (num2 < num1)
            System.out.println(""+(num2 + 1));
                num2++;

            }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I tidied your question and used code formatting on the code.  Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  It makes code easier to debug, especially code involving loops.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, I'm still trying to get a hang of using those brackets.

Comment: What code editor do you use?  (I'm guessing it is an IDE, given those `TODO` and JavaDoc comments that I removed as noise.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problems lies with the code-blocks (the stuff between {}). Especially look at how the `while`-loop behaves. What is supposed to be in the loop and what not? Also, your `if`-statement is empty. The ; closes the code-block that is handled by the `if`.

An IDE can help you detect these errors by applying syntax-formatting. The comments in your code looked like they were coming from Eclipse. Try `ctrl-shift-f` (or look it up in the menu). This automatically formats and indents your code, this makes it easier to detect errors in the structure.

Answer (score 0):

First, your conditional check should use an `or` and braces; and assign `0` to `num1`, as to prevent the loop from running if the user inputs anything outside the 1-10 range:

```
if (num1 < 1 || num1 > 10){
    num1=0;
}
```

And you can also improve your loop:

```
while (num2 < num1) {
    System.out.println( ""+ num2++ );
}
```

Also, as said by user689893, check your `{}` blocks.

Comment: If condition satisfies num1 becomes 0 and num2 is already declared 0. no iteration will be there.

Comment: @ChandraSekhar, that's the point - as it is a requirement to only accept an input between 1-10, nothing should be printed if the user enters something other than that.

Comment: sorry Marcelo, You need to edit your anser a little, so that I could upvote. Now I am unable to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class loop_lab {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("Hi user, input any number that is between 1-10");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1 = input.nextInt();
        int num2 = 1;

        if (1<=num1 && num1>=10){
            num2=1;

            while (num2 <= num1)
            {
                System.out.println("" + num2);
                num2++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since this is tagged as homework it would be better to help the asker solve his problem than to actually solve it for him

Comment: Its so simple, since you got too many syntax error i just wanted to figure it out with complete code. am i right ??

Comment: @Ramesh  The person to whom you are replying, is not the person who asked the question.  Further, I agree with their advice to 'hint' rather than 'dump code' for homework questions.

Comment: Thanks for the concern Thompson, but comparing the code side to side, it seems that I didn't give my num2 a correct value. I do agree that hints are better for learning but I was still able to see where I went wrong with my work. Thanks guys!

Comment: am so sorry @user689893 i thought you were the person who asked the question. Bit confused with numbers. sorry again.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson Thanks for your advise!! Let me try to do that here after.

Comment: @Ramesh: np, maybe it's time to set a username

Comment: @Ramesh  I was a bit hasty to down-vote.  Could you make a minor edit to your post so I can remove the down-vote?  One that might work is to fix the indentation of the code statements in the outer loop (e.g starting with `num2=1;`).  If you decide to do that, let me know in a comment.

Comment: @AndrewThompson yeah sure I will do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `if` has a stray trailing `;`  As a result, the next line is *always* run.

I make it a point to include even single line statements involved with conditional statements and loops inside `{`/`}`.  That helps make the start & end of the code block clear.  My earlier comment about the code indentation is also a factor in identifying where code block begin & end.

Answer (score 0):

in while loop just change

```
 while (num2 < num1){
        if(num2==0)
         System.out.println((num2 + 1));
        else{
           num2++;
           System.out.println(num2);

        }


            }
```

Comment: Please 1) Give tips & explanations rather than code for homework questions. 2) Leave out the redundant blank lines in code. 3) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.